# Acessing SQLite tables with Django on Ubuntu

Tags: django, sqlite, terminal

I am following the Django official documentation tutorial on how to setup the database, provided here :

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/intro/tutorial02/

After running the code below I should have any necessary database tables according to the database settings in my `mysite/settings.py`.

```
$ python manage.py migrate
```

Now I want to check those tables through the terminal (this is my problem -> I can't).

The documentation says :

`If you’re interested, run the command-line client for your database and type \dt (PostgreSQL), SHOW TABLES; (MariaDB, MySQL), .tables (SQLite), or SELECT TABLE_NAME FROM USER_TABLES; (Oracle) to display the tables Django created.`

None of those commands works on my terminal, my project is setup to be on SQlite, which is just a file on my project folder and SQLite is included in Python, so I shouldn't need to install anything else to support my database.

My questions is if I can ONLY run that command (`.tables`) on sqlite special command line and I need to install it OR is there any way I can acess it with the terminal Iam using on Django.

Any help will be HIGHLY appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can access from your terminal by running the command below:

`python manage.py dbshell`

There you type `.tables` and this gives an output of the list of names of tables.